# ajax bad request only in mapped controller

Tags: ajax, json

In my spring mvc project i have 2 controller, one of them mapped like that:

```
@Controller()
@RequestMapping("/draft")
```

I am trying to send some data from ajax like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/FootballManager/draft/draftplayer',
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
        'playerID' : playerID,
        'username' : username,
        'leaguename' : leaguename
    },
    response : 'text',
    success : function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
            alert("player drafted");
        } else {

            alert("player not drafted");
        }
    },
    error : function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        _requesComplete = true;
        alert("error= " + errorThrown);

    }
```

and method in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/draftplayer",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String draftPlayer(@RequestParam("playerID") int playerID,
            @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("leaguename") String leaguename,HttpSession session) {
        try {
       ...
            return "1";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

And I always get Bad Request, but if I put this method into another controller, which has no @RequestMapping annotation in class reference, and change url to

```
url : 'http://localhost:8080/FootballManager/draftplayer',
```

it works perfectly. I spent a lot of time for this issue, why it happens like that? (Sorry for my english..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I have method in my controller, which mapped like draft/{leaguename}, and when in send request to draft/draftplayer, it mapped to first method